# What could cause a variable to evaluate differently in the Firebug watch window?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I'm working a HTML5 + jQueryMobile + Knockout mobile application and am seeing a super-weird issue in the Firebug debugger:

Inside a method that is responsible for converting a model to a view model, I have the following code:

[image: Code]

Execution is paused at the breakpoint, and the Firebug watch window looks like this:

[image: Watches]

I'm puzzled as to why `this.model.data` can be observable and `this.model.data()` shows the correct data, yet in my code both local variables (data and data2) are undefined.

Any ideas as to what can cause something like this to happen?

Comment: What does it look like in Chrome dev tools? That'll help isolate whether it's Firebug specific

Comment: Good idea. In Chrome everything evaluates to undefined, so perhaps it's a timing issue (data is populated from an async load operation, but I shouldn't end up in the shown method until they are complete, but who knows).. thanks, will try using Chrome to investigate.

Comment: If there's async going on, statements will keep evaluating until the callback kicks in.

Comment: Yes, but I'm using knockout observables to ensure this method isn't called until ready. I suspect the problem is because it's a computed observable or something; still debugging it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was apparently causes by a timing issue that would only manifest itself in Firebug on Firefox. Using Chrome's developer tools solves the problem and lets me debug the application.